# Devise the burnination of device

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device) tag seems very much useless, since it is extremely broad. The wiki description is:

> Electronic devices: computers, smartphones, tablets, electronic
>   hardware and platforms.

There is just no way this tag makes any sense in any context. The use of the tag seems to be tossing it together with some other tag, for example [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded) [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device) or [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device) [driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/driver)

There is no way the tag can stand on its own and the meaning of it is very vague.

Comment: Perhaps `[device] should catch fire`? Not sure

Comment: Wow, that's a really bad generic tag just begging for being abused in tag-soup.

Comment: I'm more concerned with the tenuousness of the title pun. I'm also disappointed that "tenuousness" isn't a better word.

Comment: If this question is closed as dupe, it will not appear anymore in the hot meta post and be forever forgotten on the sea of valid burnination requests... I'm sad.